# Effecient way for filtering dataframe by column value

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (DF1), which contains much more rows (this is only the head of the dataframe):

```
"transactionID" "sequenceID" "eventID" "items"
"1" 29698 40928360 1 "OV4"
"2" 23561 41469527 1 "OV6"
"3" 23562 41469527 2 "OV7"
"4" 10514 41487127 1 "OV8"
"5" 10515 41487127 2 "OV9"
"6" 10516 41487127 3 "OV10"
"7" 10517 41487127 4 "OV11"
```

I would like to filter the all the rows which their maximal eventID value is over 3. As seen, each eventId is grouped by sequenceID. I would like to keep the order and the content of the rows.
The required result would be:

```
"transactionID" "sequenceID" "eventID" "items"
"4" 10514 41487127 1 "OV8"
"5" 10515 41487127 2 "OV9"
"6" 10516 41487127 3 "OV10"
"7" 10517 41487127 4 "OV11"
```

Since, only sequenceID = 41487127 contains eventID of 4. The rest contains only 1 or 2 eventID.
I used the following command:

```
> data7<-setDT(DF1)[, if(any(eventID >= 3)) .SD, by = sequenceID ]

> data7
   sequenceID transactionID eventID items
1:   41487127         10514       1   OV8
2:   41487127         10515       2   OV9
3:   41487127         10516       3  OV10
4:   41487127         10517       4  OV11
```

The position of the column transactionID was changed. Why is it? What can I do just to filter the dataframe without changing the column's positions?
Is my command is the most efficient way for such filtering?

Comment: It is because you are grouping by `sequenceID` whch takes the left most position.

Comment: Why is the position of columns so important?

Comment: Try `setDT(DF1)[,if(any(eventID>3)) .SD , sequenceID][,names(DF1),with=FALSE]`  BTW, the row ids will be reset in each operation of `data.table`.  So you wont get `4, 5, 6, 7` as row.names.

Comment: @Heroka, this is because of an algorithm that uses the location of the columns.

Comment: Thanks @akrun. In case I need to renumber the transactionID from 1..n (n end of last row num of data7). What do I have to add? And what to do in order to keep row names?

Comment: @Avi In that case, we may need to create a new sequence column before filtering.

Comment: "*I would like to filter the all the rows which their eventID column is less than 3*", I'm sorry but this description has nothing to do with the code you posted as a solution.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you say you want to filter on eventID but in the desired results you filter on transactionID.
And why not use the subset() function. Seems to me an easier way of filtering.

Comment: David, It means to keep all the rows that their maximal eventID value is over 3, I'll correct it.

Comment: What about the `sequenceID` part which somehow present in your code and no where was to be mentioned?

Comment: David, Please explain what you mean. I mentioned it and gave an example with its value.

Comment: "*I would like to filter the all the rows which their maximal eventID value is over 3. I would like to keep the order and the content of the rows.*"- This sentence doesn't mention that you want it grouped by `sequenceID`. You only mention it *after* you already provided a description of the question. This is *not* how you formulate the question, as no one knows where did that `sequenceID` popud-out of a sudden. In other words, if you wouldn't post the code, no one *ever* would understand what are you trying to do. Because your description has nothing in common with the provided code.

Comment: Thanks David, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are grouping by 'sequenceID', which becomes the first column after filtering.  But, we can rearrange using the original column names of the dataset.

```
setDT(DF1)[,if(any(eventID>3)) .SD , sequenceID][,names(DF1),with=FALSE]
#   transactionID sequenceID eventID items
#1:         10514   41487127       1   OV8
#2:         10515   41487127       2   OV9
#3:         10516   41487127       3  OV10
#4:         10517   41487127       4  OV11
```

Suppose, we need the position of the rows that were filtered, we create a row names column ('rn') using `keep.rownames` and then do the filter.

```
setDT(DF1, keep.rownames=TRUE)[, if(any(eventID>3)) .SD , sequenceID
                               ][, names(DF1), with=FALSE]
#   rn transactionID sequenceID eventID items
#1:  4         10514   41487127       1   OV8
#2:  5         10515   41487127       2   OV9
#3:  6         10516   41487127       3  OV10
#4:  7         10517   41487127       4  OV11
```